# How can I uninstall python3.9 which installed by macOS 64-bit Intel installer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I installed `Python 3.9.2` by using [macOS 64-bit Intel installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-392/).

I can find the path of the `Python 3.9` binary file.

```sh
 ⚡  which python3.9                                                            
/usr/local/bin/python3.9
```

How can I uninstall it completely? Which directories and files should I remove?

Comment: Does the installer have an uninstall function?

Comment: @ThomasSablik No, it does not have

Comment: What type of installer is it? Is it a shell script?

Comment: @ThomasSablik https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.2/python-3.9.2-macosx10.9.pkg

Answer (score 2):

You can find the installed files using the following:

List Packages with:

```sh
pkgutil --pkgs
```

Find files installed for your Python package

```sh
pkgutil --files yourpythonpackage.pkg
```

Delete the related files and run:

```sh
sudo pkgutil --forget yourpythonpackage.pkg
```

From my tests I can see:

```sh
pkgutil --pkgs | grep python

org.python.Python.PythonUnixTools-3.9
org.python.Python.PythonApplications-3.9
org.python.Python.PythonDocumentation-3.9
org.python.Python.PythonFramework-3.9
```

Files:

```
DIR: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin

2to3
2to3-3.9
idle3
idle3.9
pydoc3
pydoc3.9
python3
python3-config
python3.9
python3.9-config

DIR: /Applications/Python\ 3.9/
DIR: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9
```

(Check these two latest from packages `PythonDocumentation-3.9` and `PythonFramework-3.9`)

In my case just deleting `/Applications/Python\ 3.9/` and `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` was enough.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this method can delete all files related to `python 3.9`. But it can get me back to the python version pre-installed on the OSX system.

I will `rm -rf` below directories and files:

```sh
/usr/local/bin/python3.9-config
/usr/local/bin/python3.9
/usr/local/bin/pip3.9
/usr/local/bin/pydoc3.9
/usr/local/idle3.9
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9
```

If you have installed `brew`, you can run `brew doctor` to help you to some cleanup work.

```sh
☁  python-codelab [master] ⚡  brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew cleanup`:
  /usr/local/bin/2to3
  /usr/local/bin/2to3-3.9
  /usr/local/bin/easy_install-3.9
  /usr/local/bin/idle3
  /usr/local/bin/idle3.9
  /usr/local/bin/pip3
  /usr/local/bin/pydoc3
  /usr/local/bin/pydoc3.9
  /usr/local/bin/python3-config
```

```sh
☁  python-codelab [master] ⚡  python3 --version      
Python 3.8.2
```